# Vim quickfix double path to file with Ghc-mod

Tags: vim, filepath

I use Ghc-mod Vim for Haskell source file check. I run it on Windows with gvim. Run `:GhcModCheck` it passes file for Ghc-mod utility and outputs in a quickfix error like:

```
G:\Haskell\G:\Haskell\huffman.hs|5 col 1 warning| The import of foldl' from module `Data.List' is redundant
```

As you can see, it includes path to file two times. Of course I can't jump in that location.
It looks like Ghc-mod itself doesn't output any paths at all, then it ether vim's errorformat or Ghc-mod for Vim plugin. Strangely enough, I haven't found such cases anywhere, so it maybe my [_vimrc](http://pastie.org/8682895)

Could anyone kindly point me out where to search for clues?

Comment: Could you show us a raw error message so that we can compare with your `errorformat`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked standard quickfix window after :vimgrep and it appeared allright. It left me only ghcmod-vim as main suspect. I've carefully traced all paths manipulation and have found that utils use some function, which  reads a path and searches [a-z] regexp in it. 
The problem was that my drive letters were uppercase, so plugin treated it like a usual filename. 
I've commited a [pull request](https://github.com/eagletmt/ghcmod-vim/issues/40) to ghcmod-vim repo. Hope it'll help.
Thanks you for a concearn.